# Neo4j check if node only connected to a nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j db that contains 3 type of labels

- mom (with unique name)
- dad (with unique name)
- Timestamp

And 2 types of relationships

1. Opened the app
2. Closed the app

Each mom and dad use an app
And the db containes the connection between the time and date of the app using to the mom of dad like so:
(Mom)-[open]->(time)
Same as dad labels and close relationship.

There are multiple mom and dad using the app and I want to connect dad to mom.
**The dad and the mom that are connected use the app in the same time**
That's mean that if the dad and the mom have the same Timestamps (no more and no less) they are connected.

Now you can't count the connections, because the mom might have 4 connections to Timestamps but share only 1 Timestamp with dad, and the dad have also 4 connections to the Timestamps.

I tried do that query:

//get a dad by name
Match (d:dad {unique_name:"joe")-->(dad_ts:Timestamp)

With collect(dad_ts) as dad_ts_list

//get all the mom that connected to the all of dad Timestamp

Match (m:mom)->(mom_ts:Timestamp)

Where all(ts in dad_ts_list where (mom)->(ts))

Return m

Now I found 2 problems with this code

1. I get all the mom, when I can simply pass dad_ts and get only the mom that share Timestamp with dad and make the query faster. But some how if I pass the dad_ts it return moms that not all connected to dad_ts
2. If a mom connected to all of the dad_ts but have more connections she is not the mom.

So I tried that psodocode:

1. Get dad by unique name and the Timestamps
2. Get the mom that connected to the dad_ts
3. Get all of the Timestamp of the moms (that connected to dad_ts)
4. Remove the dad Timestamps from the mom Timestamps what leave you with a list of all of the Timestamps the un-correct mom is connected to
5. Get the mom that not connected to 4 Timestamps

So I tried something like that:

//get a dad by name

Match (d:dad {unique_name:"joe")-->(dad_ts:Timestamp)

With collect(dad_ts) as dad_ts_list, dad_ts

//get all the mom that connected to
at least one of dad Timestamp

Match (m:mom)->(dad_ts)

Match (m)->(mom_ts:Timestamp)

//option A

Where dad_ts.value <> mom_ts.value

// Some how its give me all of the mom_ts inculcated the dad_ts. I thought it's because it's datetime type, so I tried change it to string and still doesn't work.

//option B

With collect(mom_ts) as mom_ts_list, dad_ts_list, m,

//tried to filter the list

Filter(t in mom_ts_list where not t in dad_ts_list) as not_dad_ts

//And that also return all of the Timestamps inculcated the dad_ts

// not sure about the end to get the moms that not connected, because I couldn't create the Timestamps list of the wrong Timestamps, but I think it will look like that.

(m)->(ts:Timestamp)

Where none(t in not_dad_ts where ts.value = t.value)

Return m

So if you can help correct the query/you have better idea to get the mom node that **only fully connected to dad_ts** it will be great.

Comment: Look at node similarity in graph data science algorithm. It uses jaccard index, which fits your problem exactly.

Comment: It is difficult to follow without sample data. When dad timestamp are t1, t2, t3, and t4 and momA ts is t2 and momB is is t3 then how can you tell to pick momA and NOT momB?

Comment: The dad and the mom have to share all of the ts.

Comment: Can you give us sample data where you found problems on your query? Your query looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below:

```
//get a dad by name Match (d:dad {unique_name:"joe")-->(dad_ts:Timestamp)

With collect(dad_ts) as dad_ts_list

//get all the mom that connected to the all of dad Timestamp

Match (m:mom)->(mom_ts:Timestamp)

Where all(dad_ts in dad_ts_list where dad_ts = mom_ts)

Return m
```

So instead of checking (mom)->(ts), you can check dad_ts is the same with mom_ts. Let me know if it works. If it fails on a certain point, pls give us sample data. thanks.